# How to ignore folder from being processed by Webpack in NativeScript app

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I have a folder inside `project-root/app` dir that contains HTML/CSS/JS files that will be referenced by `WebView` control. The problem is Webpack processes this folder and reports many errors. How to ignore it? Thank you.

Here is one of the errors (the `bg` folder should be ignored by Webpack):

```
ERROR in ./bg/assets/css/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css' in '~\app\bg\assets\css'
 @ ./bg/assets/css/styles.css 1:87-152 2:86-151
 @ . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)(?<!\.\/\btests\b\/.*?)\.(xml|css|js|kt|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$
 @ ./app.ts
```

Comment: What kind of errors you are talking about? Can you post the error logs? Are you using any framework or just the Core flavour?

Comment: @Manoj Hi, thanks for looking at this. I've updated the question with the first error in the console. But I simply want to ignore the whole `bg` dir.

Comment: Can you also add what you have in your `style.css`, usually you add a tidal (~) infront of the path when it's inside node_modules.

Comment: @Manoj that is not the point. I want the whole `bg` dir to be ignored, no matter what I put inside. Just Webpack should ignore it and not look at it in any way. How can I do that in the `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: You can add the file to the exclude list in webpack config file.

Comment: @Manoj I am not sure where should I put the exclude list. Is it under `module.rule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may adjust webpack config to exclude certain files or folders from the bundle. There are various different ways to do it, I would use ignore plugin

In your `webpack.config.js`, under `plugins` array add the following

```
plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/bg\/assets\/css/),
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": "global.process",
            }),
```

It will exclude all files from the specific folder.